# finding mean and variance $X$ in moment generating function

Tags: probability

> For a certain random variable $X$ .
>
> Them moment Generating function is given by
>
> $M_{X}(t)=12t^4+8t^2-3t.$Then mean and variance  of $X$ is

What i try

$M'_{X}(t)=48t^3+16t-3.$ Then $M'_{X}(0)=-3$

So our mean is $-3$

And $M''_{X}(t)=144t^2+16.$ Then $M''_{X}(0)=16.$

So variance is $16$

Is my process is right. If not how can i find it mean

I also have a doubt. Is means or variance can be negative.

Please explain me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mean is correct and the mean can be negative. But $M_X''(0)$ is not the variance, it is the second moment. So $var (X)=EX^{2}-(EX)^{2}=16-(-3)^{2}=7$. The variance is always non-negative.

Comment: Thanks Professor. Got it.